# building mongo c++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

Under CentOs 7, I cloned the driver from [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver).

When I go to build it, I get an error about `libbson`. And yet `libbson` is both on the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and on the `PATH`

```
[idf@njserver build]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/lib64:/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/lib64:/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/lib64:
[idf@njserver build]$
```

The path

```
[idf@njserver build]$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64:/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/idf/.local/bin:/home/idf/bin
[idf@njserver build]$
```

Proof that `libbson` is in `/usr/lib64`

```
[idf@njserver build]$ ls /usr/lib64/libbson*
/usr/lib64/libbson-1.0  /usr/lib64/libbson-1.0.so  /usr/lib64/libbson-1.0.so.0  /usr/lib64/libbson-1.0.so.0.0.0
[idf@njserver build]$
```

Trying to build

```
[idf@njserver build]$ cmake ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.1
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- No build type selected, default is Release
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Error at src/bsoncxx/CMakeLists.txt:70 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findlibbson-1.0.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "libbson-1.0", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libbson-1.0"
  (requested version 1.9.0) with any of the following names:

    libbson-1.0Config.cmake
    libbson-1.0-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "libbson-1.0" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "libbson-1.0_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "libbson-1.0" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/idf/builds/mongo-cxx-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[idf@njserver build]$
```

**Not sure why this is happening?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by compiling the libraries **by hand** (no yum, apt etc) libbson, libmongo-c driver, and finally libmongo-cpp driver

Comment: Thanks, your own solution helped me get over this as well! :)